# Boost::ini_parser: What is the way to read specific section's values?

Tags: c++, windows, boost, ini

I am using boost::property_tree in order to read .ini file.

I know i can read specific `key(inside section) -> iniTree.get<std::string>("section.key")`.

I know i can read all values in the ini file.

I want to read only keys from specific section.

Something like that: `iniTree.get<std::vector<std::string> >("section")`.

Is it possible?

Comment: [All right. Time to say it. I think #Boost PropertyTree is an odd thing. It appears to be best at generating confusion and get abused a lot](https://twitter.com/sehetw/status/556793518946258945)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You use 'get_child' to get a subtree.

You can use `get_child_optional` in case you don't know before hand whether the section exists.

Here's a demo that shows both variations:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d8c41852110222a)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using boost::property_tree::ptree;

int main() {

    std::fstream ifs("input.txt");
    ptree pt;

    read_ini(ifs, pt);

    // let's get just the section2

    if (boost::optional<ptree&> oops = pt.get_child_optional("oops")) {
        std::cout << "There is a section `oops`\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "There is NO section `oops`\n";
    }

    ptree& sub1 = pt.get_child("section2"); // we want the CCs!
    write_ini(std::cout, sub1);
}
```

And given an input.txt of:

```
[section1]

huh=value1
slam=value2
cram=value3

[section2]

rabbits=creditcard1
die=creditcard2
eagerly=creditcard3
```

It'll print the output:

```
There is NO section `oops`
rabbits=creditcard1
die=creditcard2
eagerly=creditcard3
```

Comment: In case you're interested, here's the [live-stream](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/boost-property-tree-and-geometry-intersection/) of me answering this question. ([experiment](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=24182469#24182469))

Comment: Just realized, I never enumerated the values in the section. Here you go: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1395078691c8d67